# getting this error [error] Element id=edumenubutton-1037-btnInnerEl not found in selenium ide 2.9.0

Tags: selenium

I'm getting `[error] Element id=edumenubutton-1037-btnInnerEl not found` when I record from the site. With my code below, I'm only able to login to the page but when I cycle through other links within the page I get the aforementioned error.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="selenium.base" href="https://hob-srv-115/" />
  <title>New Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>/501/edu5/web/app.php/login/</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=textfield-1016-inputEl</td>
        <td>admin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=textfield-1017-inputEl</td>
        <td>crashtest</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>id=button-1020-btnInnerEl</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>1500</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>id=edumenubutton-1037-btnInnerEl</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>1500</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>id=educalendareventmenubutton-1263-btnEl</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the html of target page. The one above is the IDE generated script which is of less use to get the solution.

Comment: ok i have set the delay and it is working fine now.